# Accessing a mySQL database on an external server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, mysql, sql

I have a large (multi-gigabyte) SQL database on an external server. I can access it through SSH, but manually querying the data will be a major pain. I really need a GUI.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, but I can't find any applications with a GUI that'll allow me to do this. Can anybody recommend one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: this + the ssh tunnel option means no exposing of the mysql server

Comment: Or use stunnel (http://www.stunnel.org), which will setup an encrypted session without requiring a shell login.

Answer (score 2):

Best I used are:

1. [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
2. [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)
3. [Emma](http://freecode.com/projects/emma)
4. [TOra](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tora/)
5. [LibreOffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) **needed to download mysql-jdbc-connector*

Answer (score 2):

Web interface: [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) - Bringing MySQL to the Web

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) on wine in Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a paid thing isn't it?